# boot from different hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PowerEdge R710. I had it working with a 160GB Sata solid state drive no problem. That drive was removed and a new 1 TB drive was put in. The Raid settings were changed for this new drive. Now I want to use the old 160 GB solid state drive again. How can I use this again, so that I can get my old data off of that drive? Can I just redo the raid settings? I do not want to clear that drive (I am just doing this to get data off of the drive).

Thanks

Comment: Thing is that when you change a drive in a RAID array it has to build it every time so when you replaced the 1 TB instead of the 160 GB it was rebuilt..so my guess is that if put the old ssd back it'd erase all on that drive. Do you strictly need to put back the 160 GB drive on the same server?

Comment: Additionally, there is no need to boot from the old drive. Just mount it and copy your data.

Comment: Were this drives members of a RAID volume, or just individual drives connected to a RAID controller?  Was the 160GB drive a member of the same RAID volume as the 1TB drive?  What type of RAID volume was it?  Your answer almost certainly depends a lot on the specific details.

Answer (score 1):

I put the old drive back into the server and reconfigured the raid settings for the original drive, and now it seems to be working just fine with the old drive, and I can get all my data off.